# Breadcrumb trail not displaying correctly in custom module

Tags: 7, routes, breadcrumbs

I'm working on developing a custom module for Drupal 7.  Part of the module that I'm creating is a form editing component (with an entirely different aim from something like cck, which is why I am re-inventing the wheel here). I've got one page registered to display a list of all the forms, and another registered for viewing and editing a specific form.  I would like the breadcrumb on the viewing page to include a link to the listing page, however it does not appear.  I am getting "Home » Administration » Jarrow ETD System", while I would like to have a "Form Editor" component on the end.  The relevant hook_menu code looks like this:

```
$items['admin/settings/jarrow'] = array(
  'title' => t('Jarrow ETD System'),
  'description' => t('Configure the core settings for the Jarrow ETD system'),
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('jarrow_configure'),
  'access arguments' => array('administer etd'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);

$items['admin/settings/jarrow/forms'] = array(
  'title' => t('Form Editor'),
  'description' => t('View All Forms'),
  'page callback' => 'jarrow_list_forms',
  'file' => 'form_editor.inc',
  'access callback' => 'user_access',
  'access arguments' => array('administer etd'),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'weight' => 40,
);

$items['admin/settings/jarrow/forms/%/view'] = array(
  'title' => t('Form View'),
  'description' => t('View a Form'),
  'page callback' => 'jarrow_view_form',
  'page arguments' => array(4),
  'file' => 'form_editor.inc',
  'access callback' => 'user_access',
  'access arguments' => array('administer etd'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

There are a significant number of other pages registered, which I have omitted.  Aside from the fact that I probably shouldn't be using 'admin/settings' as my base url, I can't see anything wrong with the menu structure.  Oddly enough, if I add in the following code to hook_menu, I get the right result:

```
$items['admin/settings/jarrow/stuff'] = array(
  'title' => t('Stuff Editor'),
  'description' => t('View All Forms'),
  'page callback' => 'jarrow_list_forms',
  'file' => 'form_editor.inc',
  'access callback' => 'user_access',
  'access arguments' => array('administer etd'),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'weight' => 40,
);

  $items['admin/settings/jarrow/stuff/%/view'] = array(
  'title' => t('Stuff View'),
  'description' => t('View a Form'),
  'page callback' => 'jarrow_view_form',
  'page arguments' => array(4),
  'file' => 'form_editor.inc',
  'access callback' => 'user_access',
  'access arguments' => array('administer etd'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

This is exactly the same entry into hook_menu, down to the function it's calling, except for the url having "stuff" in it instead of "forms".  However, the breadcrumb trail displays properly: "Home » Administration » Jarrow ETD System » Stuff Editor".

I took a look at the inner workings of menu.inc, and traced the execution.  It appears that when Drupal assembles the menu tree for the form, it is including the child /view, whereas for "stuff" it does not.  I can't for the life of me figure out why, and I am hoping someone with experience dealing with drupal's menu system can provide some explanation as to why the menu would be constructed as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making a completely unrelated change to my hook_menu, the breadcrumb fixed itself.  I don't know why though.

Comment: My theory: the menu system is broken.  The reason why there is no relevant documentation (that I can find) is because there is no consistent  way to get items to appear in breadcrumbs.  As soon as one tries to document a solution, one finds an exception.  The exceptions are not consistent, and inexplicably, the system sometimes (but not always) heals itself.  Even posting a good bug report would be difficult, since it is hard to consistently reproduce the problem.  If anyone finds a solution, or a consistent way to reproduce the problem, please post.

Comment: In my case, I believe I was able to make some progress by deleting problematic menu items from the menu_links table.  Breadcrumbs then appear as desired when the parent and children items are all of type MENU_NORMAL_ITEM in the code (though I'm not sure the type matters), and the URLs are set up like so... parent, parent/child, parent/child2, etc.  When I do this and clear the cache, breadcrumbs then appear as they should.  Items are re-created in the menu_links table, but not with the same IDs; this could break some sites as a result, if you have code that depends on the menu link IDs.